# Doing validation across a large number of items using all()

Tags: python

I have about 100 fields I need to make sure have non-empty values. To do this I am doing:

```
if all([field1, field2, ...]):
    print 'ok'
else:
    raise
```

However, I'd like to know *which* fields have the empty values, so I can prompt the user to correct those. Is there a straightforward way to show which fields have the empty values in a large-scale validation, using `all()` or another method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that you store the 'fields' in a `dict`:

```
>>> fields = {'a': 'A', 'b': '', 'c': 'C'}
>>> [key for key, value in fields.iteritems() if not value]
['b']
```

If it is a list and you want to know the indexes where the values are empty:

```
>>> fields = ['a', 'b', '', 'd']
>>> [index for index, value in enumerate(fields) if not value]
[2]
```

Answer (score 1):

`all()` returns `False` as soon as it hits one value that falsy; it won't even finish iterating over your list. Just build two lists of valid and empty fields.

```
valid_fields = [f for f in fields if f] 
empty_fields = [f for f in fields if not f]
if empty_fields:
    raise
```

Comment: This isn't bad except for the fact that you're iterating `fields` twice and creating two new lists to-boot. This method could be costly depending on the size of `fields`.

Answer (score 1):

A list of empty tuples is probably not that useful, so you probably want their index.
Try

```
[i for i, field in enumerate(fields) if not field]
```

Answer (score 0):

just for fun...

```
any( do_something(index) for index, field in enumerate(mylist) if not field )
```

just make sure do_something() dont return anything or return a false value.